# Highcharts yAxis text rotation issue in IE8

Tags: internet-explorer-8, highcharts

[image: Demo]

Hi, I am using the Highcharts library for drawing charts, however I came across an issue with the yAxis in Internet Explorer.

How can be yAxis text displayed correctly rotated in IE8 and IE7 ?

Comment: I'm currently using IE8, and that demo looks fine to me. Did you modify it at all?

Comment: Which version of IE do you use? Because in my ie8 it looks like well.

Comment: @MatthewKremer I didn't modify anything. Just open the link http://www.highcharts.com/demo/ under internet explorer with Browser Mode less than ie9 and the issue will appear.

Comment: @Sebastian Bochan  10.1, but I am testing the compatibility with older versions of explorer.

Comment: it's worth pointing out that IE's compatibility modes do have some bugs and quirks that make them different from a real copy of IE8 (or whichever version you're testing). If you want to *really* test old your compatibility with versions of IE, you need to use real copies of the IE versions you want to test. Compatibility mode is not a reliable testing tool.

Comment: In IE8 Standards mode in IE8 the example is fine with me. @Spudley is correct though, make sure you are NOT in compatibility mode.

Comment: Have you tried use master branch version http://github.highcharts.com/master/highcharts.src.js  ?

Answer (score 5):

I have the same problem and I figured out that this problem is caused by ie8 emulator. So if you use a native ie8(ie8 from windows xp), will work without problem. On highcharts code there is an method to create css properties, and on this, highcharts create the property for each browser. if ie -ms-transform, if mozilla moz-transform, if web-kit ...

But for browser earlier than ie9 css3 rotate is not supported, so there is a matrix rotate, and this guy(progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Matrix), dont works on ie8- emulator.

Try to run your code on winxp native ie8 and will work.
;D

Answer (score 0):

Based on you're description of the issue, I believe this will help. Note the only workaround is to apply a background color to the label.

https://github.com/highslide-software/highcharts.com/issues/663

Comment: Thanks, but the problem concerns the wrong rotation of the yAxis label, the fix with background did not help.